# Call a custom attribute method from the view model

Tags: aurelia

I have a custom attribute with a method to show and hide some HTML content, I've attached the attribute to an element in a view model.

How can I call a method defined in the custom attribute from the view model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the custom attribute's view-model, just put the custom attribute on the element a second time, but this time put `.ref="viewModelPropertyName"` on to the attribute. Then, in the parent view-model, you can access methods on the attribute using `viewModelPropertyName` (or whatever name you gave it). You can see an example of this here: https://gist.run/?id=9819e9bf73f6bb43b07af355c5e166ad

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./has-method"></require>

  <div has-method="hello" has-method.ref="theAttribute"></div>

  <button click.trigger="callMethod()">Call method</button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  callMethod() {
    const result = this.theAttribute.someMethod('blah');
  }
}
```

**has-method.js**

```
export class HasMethodCustomAttribute {
  someMethod(foo) {
    console.log('someMethod called with foo = ' + foo + ', this.value = ' + this.value);

    return `Hello ${foo}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do it, but I believe the ideal would be binding a property from your custom-attribute to your view-model. For example:

```
MyCustomAttribute {

  @bindable showOrHide; //use this to show or hide your element
}

MyViewModel {

   visible = false;
}
```

Usage:

```
<div my-custom-attribute="showOrHide.bind: visible"></div>
```

So, whenever you change `visible` you will also change `showOrHide`.

Nevertheless, is good to remember that Aurelia already has a `show` and `if` custom-attributes:

```
<div show.bind="visible" my-custom-attribute></div>
<div if.bind="visible" my-custom-attribute></div>
```

Make sure if you really need to create this behaviour in your custom-attribute.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. I've posted the correct answer.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I know that the answer doesn't show how to call a custom-attribute method, but don't you think that calling a method from the custom-attribute just to hide/show an element is a completely overkill?

Comment: I completely agree with you. But at the same time I'm over here sipping from my "Accepted Answer" beer, and it tastes pretty good. :-)

Comment: But seriously, you are correct that the strategy OP wants to use is the wrong strategy to accomplish what they want to accomplish, but at the same time, it's helpful to answer the question as is.. Except when I choose to answer them in the way that you've answered here. You know how it is.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful in your answer to show the `showOrHideChanged` callback. Both of our answers are useful for the OP.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I know how it is. http://imgur.com/jABJ2dR. Today I pressed the wrong button. No beer for me.

Comment: @AshleyGrant, @FabioLuz, Is there a way to set this up so that the binding is to a method in the Custom Attribute, rather than just a boolean?  Seems like I should be able to do a two way binding that would allow the user of the custom element to bind to the callback pointing to my `Custom Attribute` (and call it from the view model of the custom element that is using the custom attribute, with out having to setup a `ref` to the whole custom attribute.)

Comment: (The problem with the boolean approach is that then you have to deal with setting it back to false, and dealing with issues when it has not automatically set itself back to false.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without the need for a `ref`.  Here is an example that shows how.

It calls a `showNotification` method on the custom attribute from the custom element using the custom attribute.

In the custom attribute:

```
@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) showNotificationCallback: ()=> void;

bind() {
    this.showNotificationCallback = this.showNotification.bind(this);
}

 showNotification() {
    // Your code here
}
```

In the custom element view (Note the absence of parens in the value of this binding):

```
 <div notification="show-notification-callback.bind: showSaveSuccessNotification;></div>
```

In the custom element view-model:

```
// Show the save success view to the user.
if (typeof this.showSaveSuccessNotification=== 'function') {
    this.showSaveSuccessNotification();
}
```